# Dependent dropdown list doesn't work - symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dropdown

I want to generate dependent dropdown list in Symfony 3.4

I have followed the exact example(copy and paste) : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/652/how-to-create-a-dependent-select-dependent-dropdown-in-symfony-3

I have created all the tables and populated them.

I really didn't change any thing I want to test the code as it is before using it in my project.

the result :

[image]

**Update:**

Person entity:

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\City
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\City")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Neighborhood
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Neighborhood")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="neighborhood_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $neighborhood;
```

**Person type**

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
            ->add('lastName');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
    }

    protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, City $city = null) {
        // 4. Add the province element
        $form->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'data' => $city,
            'placeholder' => 'Select a City...',
            'class' => 'AppBundle:City'
        ));

        $neighborhoods = array();
        if ($city) {
            $repoNeighborhood = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Neighborhood');

            $neighborhoods = $repoNeighborhood->createQueryBuilder("q")
                ->where("q.city = :cityid")
                ->setParameter("cityid", $city->getId())
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
        }
        $form->add('neighborhood', EntityType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Select a City first ...',
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Neighborhood',
            'choices' => $neighborhoods
        ));
    }

    function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $city = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->find($data['city']);

        $this->addElements($form, $city);
    }

    function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $person = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $city = $person->getCity() ? $person->getCity() : null;
        $this->addElements($form, $city);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Person'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_person';
    }
}
```

views/Person.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Person creation</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('person_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#appbundle_person_city').change(function () {
            var citySelector = $(this); 
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('person_list_neighborhoods') }}",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    cityid: citySelector.val()
                },
                success: function (neighborhoods) {
                    var neighborhoodSelect = $("#appbundle_person_neighborhood");

                    neighborhoodSelect.html('');
                    neighborhoodSelect.append('<option value> Select a neighborhood of ' + citySelector.find("option:selected").text() + ' ...</option>');

                    $.each(neighborhoods, function (key, neighborhood) {
                        neighborhoodSelect.append('<option value="' + neighborhood.id + '">' + neighborhood.name + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("An error ocurred while loading data ...");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Person controller:

```
class PersonController extends Controller
{
       /**
     * Returns a JSON string with the neighborhoods of the City with the providen id.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function listNeighborhoodsOfCityAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $neighborhoodsRepository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Neighborhood");

        $neighborhoods = $neighborhoodsRepository->createQueryBuilder("q")
            ->where("q.city = :cityid")
            ->setParameter("cityid", $request->query->get("cityid"))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        $responseArray = array();
        foreach($neighborhoods as $neighborhood){
            $responseArray[] = array(
                "id" => $neighborhood->getId(),
                "name" => $neighborhood->getName()
            );
        }

        // Return array with structure of the neighborhoods of the providen city id
        return new JsonResponse($responseArray);
      }
}
```

**AppBundle/config/routing.yml**

```
person_list_neighborhoods:
    path:     /get-neighborhoods-from-city
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Person:listNeighborhoodsOfCity" }
    methods:  GET
```

Comment: Show us some code, pretty sure if it was the exact same code from a tutorial you should not have any problem.

Comment: Provide [mcve] please

Comment: Just to be safe, did you actually named your bundle "AppBundle"? Also, on the web browser, do you see any HTML element having `id="appbundle_person_city"`?

Comment: yes I named my bundle AppBundle ,and no on my browser just the [ ]  is displayed nothing else